# Laptop having boot issues

Tags: boot

I’ve just installed Elementary OS on my Toshiba Laptop and now I am getting boot issues. To turn the computer on after shutting down I have to force shutdown twice to get it to startup. The first time I just get a blank screen. I never used to have this problem when I used to run Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your bios and check your boot settings.

Make sure that your Linux install is set to launch first. Sometimes the boot order of the operating systems installed on your hard drive get shuffled. You will want to make sure Linux takes precedent over Windows, or your computer will boot weird.

Answer (score 0):

i already set up linux to boot first yet, many times my boot will stuck at dell logo.
i need to force shutdown few times until manage to go grub boot manager.